# How to monitor live SQL queries in DB2 9.1 LUW

Tags: performance, db2, monitoring

I use system views in Oracle to find worst queries that apps run and tune the DB by adding indexes and that help when developing an app in case you get stuck on performance problems; now I'd like to do the same thing in DB2 9.1 LUW but really I can find nothing, even after reading a DB2 manuals on Safari Books, am I missign something? big?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although there are numerous performance monitoring tools available from both from IBM and 3rd parties, you use the DB2 snapshot facility to see what's going on in the database.

You can either use the `GET SNAPSHOT` command or, conveniently, IBM has exposed these snapshots through views, like Oracle.

The manuals describe all of the views available in DB2 9.1:  [Supported Routines and Views](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9/topic/com.ibm.db2.udb.admin.doc/doc/r0023485.htm)

See, specifically, the section entiled "Snapshot Routines and Views"

Answer (score 3):

If you are using DB2 in Linux or Unix system, a good tools for monitoring is db2top. In the last versión of DB2, this tool is integrated with the product.
In the last version of DB2, you have the table SYSCAT.TOP_DYNAMIC_SQL and SYSCAT.STATEMENTS.